# The tests on my cs50 edge filter program are failing

Tags: c, filter, cs50

I'm working on the edge program for cs50. I have had a lot of problems with this program but I feel like I'm getting closer. If anyone could help me with any ideas for what could be going wrong I'd be very grateful.

Here is my code:

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
{
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
    {
        copy[h][w] = image[h][w];
    }
}

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        int gxred = 0;
        int gxgreen = 0;
        int gxblue = 0;
        int gyred = 0;
        int gygreen = 0;
        int gyblue = 0;
        for (int r = -1; r < 2; r++)
        {
            for (int s = -1; s < 2; s++)
            {
                if ((y + r < height && y + r >= 0) && (x + s < width && x + s >= 0))
                {
                    if (r == -1 || r == 1)
                    {
                        gxred += copy[y + r][x + s].rgbtRed * s;
                        gxgreen += copy[y + r][x + s].rgbtGreen * s;
                        gxblue += copy[y + r][x + s].rgbtBlue * s;
                    }
                    if (r == 0)
                    {
                        gxred += copy[y + r][x + s].rgbtRed * (s * 2);
                        gxgreen += copy[y + r][x + s].rgbtGreen * (s * 2);
                        gxblue += copy[y + r][x + s].rgbtBlue * (s * 2);
                    }

                }
                if ((y + s < height && y + s >= 0) && (x + r < width && x + r >= 0))
                {
                    if (s == -1 || s == 1)
                    {
                        gyred += copy[y + s][x + r].rgbtRed * s;
                        gygreen += copy[y + s][x + r].rgbtGreen * s;
                        gyblue += copy[y + s][x + r].rgbtBlue * s;
                    }
                    if (s == 0)
                    {
                        gyred += copy[y + s][x + r].rgbtRed * (s * 2);
                        gygreen += copy[y + s][x + r].rgbtGreen * (s * 2);
                        gyblue += copy[y + s][x + r].rgbtBlue * (s * 2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int red = round(sqrt((gxred * gxred) + (gyred * gyred)));
        int green = round(sqrt((gxgreen * gxgreen) + (gygreen * gygreen)));
        int blue = round(sqrt((gxblue * gxblue) + (gyblue * gyblue)));

        if (red > 255)
        {
            red = 255;
        }
        if (blue > 255)
        {
            blue = 255;
        }
        if (green > 255)
        {
            green = 255;
        }

        image[y][x].rgbtRed = red;
        image[y][x].rgbtGreen = green;
        image[y][x].rgbtBlue = blue;

    }
}
return;
}
```

Here are my errors:

:( edges correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "210 150 60\n", not "199 150 60\n"

:( edges correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "213 228 255\n", not "191 198 255\n"

:( edges correctly filters pixel in corner
    expected "76 117 255\n", not "58 92 248\n"

:( edges correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "58 92 248\n191..."

:( edges correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "58 92 248\n191..."

Comment: Can you share what this code is supposed to do? Detecting the edges?

Answer (score 1):

the gx, gy for R, G and B might change through the running of if.

TEST: You might want to print out their value before the "passing back value to image" loop

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is still existent:

Comments would be really helpful.. and a float-cast for the calculating maybe. I don't know if sqrt converts its result automatically or if you get a sqrt-int.

Currently I am doing it myself, so I will see how mine works when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

I just passed check50 and submitted my code. I guess the error message you received indicated some logic flaws in your "if" conditions, which didn't handle edge and corner pixels well. Yesterday I spent several hours trying to figure out how to deal with those edges and corners without any success, that was really painful. Then suddenly I got a brilliant idea: when making a copy of the original image, you can also add four black edges to the copy, so in the copy image, you have the original image in the middle, surrounded by four black edges. Then you only need to deal with the middle pixels, no more hassles with edge or corner pixels. With this idea in mind, writing the code is a piece of cake. If you need, I can post my code here.